# offline access in google+ using scope

Tags: java, google-plus

I'm using following scopes to get the google+ authorization and also the access token in my database.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read

How to enable offline authorization box again  for the same client id and client secret.
Can someone please suggest which scope is used to get offline access?